# How to disable the <a> link and resume it after?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that is similar to http://tv.sky.com/tv-guide/#/day/0.

I used ["DragScroll"](https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll) to make the program area work, and it works.

But here's the problem, I need to prevent the `a` for keep getting clicked after the drag. So I tried using `preventDefault()`, and actually it works! but how do I resume the link back so the user can click on it if they weren't `dragging`? What's could be the event for it?

Comment: you could use a timeout?

Comment: You can add a flag that you set to true when dragging and to false when you finish and in click event you call preventDefault when falg is true.

Comment: Set a global Boolean on `dragstart` to `true` and on `dragend` to `false`. When the link is clicked, check to see if the Boolean value is true or false to determine whether to prevent the click.

Comment: `dragstart` and `dragend` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this code:

```
var down = false;
var drag = false;
$('...').mousedown(function() {
   down = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
   down = drag = false;
}).mousemove(function() {
   if (down) {
       drag = true;
   }
}).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   if (drag) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

used something similar to setTimeout instead.

```
var golocation = function() {
        var href = $(this)[0].dataset.href;
        window.location = href;
    }

var start_time;

    $('a')
    .on('mousedown', function(e) {
        start_time = new Date().getTime();
    })
    .on('mouseup', function(e) {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now - start_time < 100) {
            golocation.call(this);
        };
    });
```